# how to set a variable or store selected item from drop down list

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I am making a registration form which has some drop down selection options (made with bootstrap) how do I store which option was selected from my drop down and make use of that value? I want to select an option and have it stored so I can make use of it to store information in a database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="console.log(this.value)">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

Whenever the option changes, `this.value` gets changed.
`this` is nothing but a reference of the select component.
You can use this to call your own function to fire HttpRequest.